# NestJS - Inject service into Pipe to fetch from DB

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to inject a service into a PipeTransform class to fetch an entry from DB.

I have tried the solution in this answer but I am getting a different error
[Inject service into pipe in NestJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63062048/inject-service-into-pipe-in-nestjs)

*`sample.pipe.ts`*

```js
@Injectable()
export class SamplePipe implements PipeTransform<any> {
  constructor(private readonly sampleService: SampleService) {}

  async transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const id = parseInt(value, 10);
    let sample: SampleEntiy = await this.sampleService.findOne(id);
    if (!sample) throw new NotFoundException('Sample Not Found');
    return sample;
  }
}
```

*`sample.controller.ts`*

```js
@Controller('sample')
export class SampleController {
  constructor(private readonly sampleService: SampleService) {}

  @Get(':id')
  async findOne(@Param('id', SamplePipe) id: SampleEntiy): Promise<SampleEntiy> {
    return sample;
  }

}
```

I get the following error at `return sample` in the controller

```
Type '<T>(notifier: Observable<any>) => MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>' is missing the following properties from type 'SampleEntiy': id, value, isActivets(2739)
```

On forcing it to return using `any` I get the following response in my browser

```js
function sample(notifier) {
return lift_1.operate(function (source, subscriber) {
var hasValue = false;
var lastValue = null;
source.subscribe(new OperatorSubscriber_1.OperatorSubscriber(subscriber, function (value) {
hasValue = true;
lastValue = value;
}));
var emit = function () {
if (hasValue) {
hasValue = false;
var value = lastValue;
lastValue = null;
subscriber.next(value);
}
};
notifier.subscribe(new OperatorSubscriber_1.OperatorSubscriber(subscriber, emit, noop_1.noop));
});
}
```

I understand that it is to do with async. The [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#class-validator) say async is supported

> First, note that the transform() method is marked as async. This is possible because Nest supports both synchronous and asynchronous pipes. We make this method async because some of the class-validator validations can be async (utilize Promises).

And I am trying something mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#transformation-use-case):

> Another useful transformation case would be to select an existing user entity from the database using an id supplied in the request:
>
> ```
> @Get(':id') 
> findOne(@Param('id', UserByIdPipe) userEntity:UserEntity) {
>   return userEntity; 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the `sample` function from the `rxjs` package here (sic!):

```
@Get(':id')
async findOne(@Param('id', SamplePipe) id: SampleEntiy): Promise<SampleEntiy> {
  return sample;
}
```

The parameter is called `id`, and you probably meant to return it instead, or even better, rename it to `sample`:

```
@Get(':id')
async findOne(@Param('id', SamplePipe) sample: SampleEntiy): Promise<SampleEntiy> {
  return sample;
}
```

Comment: I really need to find myself a buddy to review my code. Thank you so much! wasted hours on this. VSCode auto-imported `sample` from `rxjs` I realized that now. Using TS I was confident that I would get an error if it was not defined.